# Is it bad (performance wise) to pass unused viewdata to every page in MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I have a site that support multilanguage, I use ViewData to achieve this, for example I have 2 pages (Home and Register).

View:

Home.cshtml

```
<p>@ViewData("Home")</p>
```

Register.cshtml

```
<p>@ViewData("UserName")</p>
<p>@ViewData("EmailAddress")</p>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Home()
{
     ViewData("Home") = GetLang("Home", langcode); //function to get the text(cached) based on language code like english, spanish, etc
     return View();
}

public ActionResult Register()
{
     ViewData("UserName") = GetLang("UserName", langcode);
     ViewData("EmailAddress") = GetLang("EmailAddress", langcode);
     return View();
}
```

I have a hard time typing ViewData that I need in every page, so I was thinking of something like if I make a method that contains all ViewData and call it in every ActionResult.

Example :

```
public void GetAllViewData(string langcode)
{
     ViewData("Home") = GetLang("Home", langcode);
     ViewData("UserName") = GetLang("Home", langcode);
     ViewData("EmailAddress") = GetLang("EmailAddress", langcode);
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Home()
{
     GetAllViewData(langcode);
     return View();
}

public ActionResult Register()
{
     GetAllViewData(langcode);
     return View();
}
```

Is it bad performance wise (all text is cached on AppStart)? because "UserName" and "EmailAddress" ViewData aren't used in HomePage.

Any help will be appreciated and sorry for bad english.

Comment: Good time to start using ViewModel. Did you consider that?

Comment: Yes, but one page can contains more than 20 text, so it is just not effective  for me to use 20 properties in one ViewModel and changing everything from scratch is just not possible anymore since it will take too much effort.

Comment: Kindly consider using resource (resx) files for localization. [link](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-multi-lingual-site-with-localization).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will affect the performance, but not by much (assuming of course that the `GetLang` method isn't expensive to call).

Instead of putting the data in the `ViewData`, you can use a model for the view that gets the data when needed:

```
public class LanguageModel {

  private int _langcode;

  public LanguageModel(int langcode) {
    _langcode = langcode;
  }

  public string this[string name] {
    get {
      return GetLang(name, _langcode);
    }
  }

}
```

In the action methods you create a model for each view using the language code:

```
public ActionResult Home() {
 return View(new LanguageModel(langcode));
}

public ActionResult Register() {
 return View(new LanguageModel(langcode));
}
```

In the view you specify the type of the model in the `@Page` tag, for example:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyApp.LanguageModel>
```

Then in the view you would use `Model["Home"]` instead of `ViewData("Home")`.

Comment: sorry for noob question, but what does this method do and how does it work?

public string this[string name]

Comment: @warheat1990: It's an indexer; a property that lets you use bracket syntax to access a value. You can use a regular method instead if you feel more comfortable with that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concirned about expensive evaluation of language specific properties which might not be used in some of the pages, you can try to create a custom model with empty state and lazy getters, and access that with the `ViewBag.

```
public class AppModel
{
    private readonly string _lang;

    public AppModel(string lang)
    {
        _lang = lang;
    }

    public string Home { get { return GetLanguageSpecific("Home"); } }

    public string UserName { get { return GetLanguageSpecific("UserName"); } }

    public string EmailAddress { get { return GetLanguageSpecific("Email Address"); } }

    private string GetLanguageSpecific(string key)
    {
        // fake implementation.
        return string.Format("Requested a string: {0} for language: {1}", key, _lang);
    }
}
```

Then, implement a base controller class, which sets the shared data in the ViewBag (ViewBag is just a wrapper around the ViewData with dynamic notation), and derive your controller classes from that:

```
 public class CommonAppController : Controller
 {
     protected CommonAppController()
     {
         ViewBag.Common = new AppModel("en");
     }
 }

 public class RegisterController : CommonAppController
 { //...
```

Now you can write the following in the views:

```
 <p>@ViewBag.Common.UserName</p>
```

This way, the properties are evaluated only when requested, and you have only an inexpensive object of type AppModel with no state created per each instance of a controller.

UPDATE: There was an error in my CommonAppController code. Should be `ViewBag.Common`, not `ViewBag["Common"]`